# Flume Installation On Ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume

I want to install Apache Flume  1.4.0 on ubuntu to move data and store it into HDFS but i couldn't find an installation guide that show how to install flume correctly.I downloaded the binary zip.  any help please ?

Answer (score 4):

Apache Flume Installation Steps in Ubuntu :

```
Step 1 : Download the Latest Version of Flume. 

Step 2 : tar –xzvf apache-flume-1.5.0-bin.tar.gz

Step 3 : sudo mv apache-flume-1.5.2-bin /usr/local/flume

Step 4 : sudo nano ~/.bashrc

Step 5 : export FLUME_HOME=/usr/local/flume
export FLUME_CONF_DIR=$FLUME_HOME/conf
export FLUME_CLASS_PATH=$FLUME_CONF_DIR
export PATH=$FLUME_HOME/bin:$PATH

Step 6 : 

cp conf/flume-env.sh.template conf/flume-env.sh
Step 7 : 

sudo nano conf/flume-env.sh
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms100m -Xmx200m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
Step 8: 
sudo nano flume-conf.properties.template 


agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory
agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 100

# Define a source on agent and connect to channel memoryChannel.
agent.sources.tail-source.type = exec
agent.sources.tail-source.command = tail -F /opt/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-node1.log
agent.sources.tail-source.channels = memoryChannel

# Define a sink that outputs to logger.
agent.sinks.log-sink.channel = memoryChannel
agent.sinks.log-sink.type = logger

agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = memoryChannel
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://node1:8020/flumedata/
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream

# Activate channel, source and sinks
agent.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sources = tail-source
agent.sinks = log-sink hdfs-sink
Start Flume-ng agent

source ~/.bashrc

flume-ng agent -n agent -f conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console
flume-ng --help
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the Cloudera CDH apt repository you can install Flume from packages.  Check out this [guide](https://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_12.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add this file

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/flume.repo
```

with this content

```
[flume]
Name=Packages for flume
baseurl=http://archive.cloudera.com/redhat/cdh/3/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

This will tell your  yum command for a location to lookup to install the flume-ng

Then of course it is as simple as :

```
sudo yum install flume-ng
```

Comment: I just came to my own answer and tried to upvote it.  Then pleasently surprised it was me who had done this a while ago. :)